# Authentication with Laravel 6 and passport Use Custom fields and entity

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-6

I'm trying to make authentication via api in laravel, use custom fields to login and also use custom  fields instead of  the default Email, I'm not able to do that and I'm quite lost. Don't know if it is even possible.

So far I tried this:

```
otherusers entity
- idnumber
- password
```

auth.php

```
    'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],

        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'passport',
            'provider' => 'otherusers',
            'hash' => false,
        ],
],
```

```
    'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Domain\Entities\User::class,
        ],
        'otherusers' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Domain\Entities\OtherUser::class,
        ],
    ],
```

And then In the authcontroller I try to use this.

```
$credentials = [ 'idnumber' => $theidnumber , 'password' => $thepassword ]
Auth::guard('api')->check($credentials);
//Also tried with attempt but it says unknown method.
```

Obiously I adapted the naming, 
any hint?

Comment: Have you implemented the [`findForPassport` function](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/passport#customizing-the-username-field) yet?